# Macro in visual Studio 2010 that loads settings file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros

I'm just looking for a way (maybe a macro?) to load a settings file.
Ideally I'd like to be able to run this as a shortcut from the desktop too.
I googled it, but maybe I didn't hit the right keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a macro that works for me.

```
Sub MySub()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/import:""<full path to settings file>""")
End Sub
```

Some Docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.executecommand.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
function Import-VisualStudioSettingsFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string] $FullPathToSettingsFile,
        [string] $DevEnvExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe",
        [int] $SecondsToSleep = 20 # should be enough for most machines
    )

    if(-not (Test-Path $DevEnvExe)) {
        throw "Could not find visual studio at: $DevEnvExe - is it installed?"
    }

    if(-not (Test-Path $FullPathToSettingsFile)) {
        throw "Could not find settings file at: $FullPathToSettingsFile"
    }

    $SettingsStagingFile = "C:\Windows\temp\Settings.vssettings" # must be in a folder without spaces
    Copy-Item $FullPathToSettingsFile $SettingsStagingFile -Force -Confirm:$false

    $Args = "/Command `"Tools.ImportandExportSettings /import:$SettingsStagingFile`""
    Write-Verbose "$Args"
    Write-Host "Setting Tds Options, will take $SecondsToSleep seconds"
    $Process = Start-Process -FilePath $DevEnvExe -ArgumentList $Args -Passthru
    Sleep -Seconds $SecondsToSleep #hack: couldnt find a way to exit when done
    $Process.Kill()
}
```