# Export/Import Visual Studio Settings from Command Line

Tags: visual-studio, automation, settings

How do I export/import VS 2010/2012 settings from the Command Line or using C#? Is it even possible without resorting to GUI Automation?

Comment: + more info at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3636294/492

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve **import** by providing a settings file with the `/ResetSettings` argument.

```
devenv /ResetSettings c:\full\path\to\your\own.vssettings
```

This works from VS2005 onwards.

Although you can **import** from the command line, AFAIK there is no **export** functionality from the commandline. For that you could use a macro:

```
Sub ExportMacro()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/export:own.vssettings")
End Sub
```

Or from a commandline c# application (/reference EnvDte)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var filename = "own.vssettings";
     var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
                                GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE"); // version neutral

     dte.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/export:" + filename);
}
```

To import the from the macro and/or c# program replace */export* with */import*

[Msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx)

Comment: And to Import from a macro? And what is `owncsharp`?

Comment: switch export to import and whats behind the colon is the filename.

Comment: Any way to import only the settings in the file, without resetting everything?

Comment: @NelsonRothermel I don't think so

Comment: You can selectively export, so I was hoping I could selectively import without resetting.  I'm thinking the `Tools.ImportandExportSettings` way might let me just do just the import.  I'll have to give that a try.  Even if it doesn't work your answer is helpful.

Comment: Note that /resetsettings really does reset *all* settings, and then it will import your .vssettings after that is done. So if your .vssettings file is partial (in my case, just the C# settings), you cannot use /resetsettings to import it without paving over everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Without resetting, In PowerShell:

```
function Import-VisualStudioSettingsFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string] $FullPathToSettingsFile,
        [string] $DevEnvExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe",
        [int] $SecondsToSleep = 20 # should be enough for most machines
    )

    if(-not (Test-Path $DevEnvExe)) {
        throw "Could not find visual studio at: $DevEnvExe - is it installed?"
    }

    if(-not (Test-Path $FullPathToSettingsFile)) {
        throw "Could not find settings file at: $FullPathToSettingsFile"
    }

    $SettingsStagingFile = "C:\Windows\temp\Settings.vssettings" # must be in a folder without spaces
    Copy-Item $FullPathToSettingsFile $SettingsStagingFile -Force -Confirm:$false

    $Args = "/Command `"Tools.ImportandExportSettings /import:$SettingsStagingFile`""
    Write-Verbose "$Args"
    Write-Host "Setting Tds Options, will take $SecondsToSleep seconds"
    $Process = Start-Process -FilePath $DevEnvExe -ArgumentList $Args -Passthru
    Sleep -Seconds $SecondsToSleep #hack: couldnt find a way to exit when done
    $Process.Kill()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Import and export is possible from **powershell**. To export the current settings to `$outFileName`:

This requires that visual studio is running. (you can do that from the script by just calling devenv).

First, add enclose the file name in `"` to allow spaces in file paths:

```
$filenameEscaped="`"$outFileName`""

$dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0") 
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", '/export:'+$filenameEscaped)
```

Optionally, exit:

```
$dte.ExecuteCommand("File.Exit")
```

To **import**, either use the `/ResetSettings` option to devenv.exe. Or, to import without resetting:`

```
$dte.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", '/import:'+$filenameEscaped)
```

---

This answer is a port of @rene's C# answer. For some reason, I had to specify the exact version of visual studio `DTE.15.0`.

Comment: I repeat: "This requires that visual studio is running. (you can do that from the script by just calling devenv)." For everyone like me who was just trying the commands without reading so far.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell, this will start up visual studio (devenv.exe), and execute the command. Here it will export all the settings to the given path:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE

.\devenv.exe /Command "Tools.ImportandExportSettings /export:c:/temp/mysettings.vssettings"
```