# How to execute Visual Studio commands in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to execute Visual Studio command to import/export settings file in C#.
Can I do this using DTE2. If yes how to do?

How to initialize DTE2 and do..Please give the complete code.

Can I make use of this?

```
ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/export:\"C:/temp/setttings.vssettings\"")
```

If yes - then how to initialize dte2 and call the method?

Comment: How to call the ExecuteCommand method?

Comment: Are you finding like [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21456294/13107433)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to execute Visual Studio command to import/export settings file in c#.

First, you need to install nuget package ->`EnvDTE`.

Second, you can use the following console app to get the settings file.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filename = "D:\\own.vssettings";
            var dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
                                       GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.16.0"); // version neutral

            dte.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "/export:" + filename);
        }
    }
```

We need to note that if your vs version is vs 2010, we should use `VisualStudio.DTE.10.0`,

If your vs version is vs2013, we should use `VisualStudio.DTE.12.0`, If your vs version is

vs2017 or later, we should use `VisualStudio.DTE.16.0`.

My vs version is vs2017, so I used `VisualStudio.DTE.16.0`.

Result:(The part of setting file)

[image]