# Visual Studio Community. Clone all projects (on local machine) from a Windows (11) account to a new created Windows account (same machine)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, user-accounts

I have been developing Visual Studio Community projects inside a Windows 11 account.
Recently, I needed to move to another account (on the same machine), but as expected, Desktop is almost empty (bald new account) and also, as expected, Visual Studio projects are not accesible from this new account.
I know I can raw copy folders from old account to new but I suspect that won't be clean.

Is it possible to make any kind of well done migration?
(because also I guess some configuration adjustments in the new account's Visual Studio would not receive well those old projects as there were developed/configured in certain ways).

I am obviously talking about local. Those projects are on my hard-disk. Perhaps there is the possibility of cloning them to a Visual Studio "cloud account" (?¿) and working with them from there or downloading local again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export/Import Visual Studio Settings from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455741/export-import-visual-studio-settings-from-command-line)

Comment: For exporting and importing settings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455741/export-import-visual-studio-settings-from-command-line (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/import-and-export-settings-command?view=vs-2022). For the source files (which probably are inside your Documents directory), just move them somewhere accessible to your new account.

Comment: @CodeCaster As i don't want to make a mess and as i think my title/question would be good for other people searching even to reach your links, would you mind putting an example (valuable answer?) with "foo", "bar"... Because i guess, there are gonna be... Not many lines of commands? 
For migrating the raw data, i guess is just copying to destination respecting the tree structure ("mounting" over destination same folders). 
But could you propose/explain the more subtle part? Settings (?) part?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't want to end writing (without knowing what i am exactly doing because grabbing just in part things) a script of... Who knows... 20 lines... Where perhaps 12 lines has nonsense in my case, etc. 
The link you suggested (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455741/export-import-visual-studio-settings-from-command-line) is not quite clear. It has a lot of controversy. There are lots of "that worked for me/that didn't work for me comments/don't do that"). Even the title is too cryptical and too minimalistic in my humble opinion. Not the right reference for clarity. Thank you!

Comment: @CodeCaster I think i would need, for example, something like: 
"What you need to move are just this two things:
- The files.
- The foo.bar.settings file. 
That's all. First is obvious. Second you can do it in this two ways: copy directly this file to this folder, etc... Or using cli, ".... ". That is what i think i am needing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into your old account, open Visual Studio, click Tools --> Import and Export Settings, then export them and import them again in your new account.

For the source files (which probably are inside your old user's Documents directory), just move them somewhere accessible to your new account.